# In windows 8.1 How to stop an application from killing other applications?

Tags: windows, usb, permissions, usb-flash-drive

I have a distant learning course for an entrance exam. They've provided me a pendrive which has all the course material videos etc.

It can be accessed only after I install the software that comes with it.

Now the thing is it will expire after a couple of months and the software won't allow me to login.

For this reason, I want to record all the video lectures and save them on my disk.

I tried to use some third party softwares like camstudio etc. But the problem is, the pendrive application detects if there is any other software running while it is running and kills it.

Even a browser will be closed if opened while the pendrive softaware is running.

Now, how do I record the screen? is there any way to make the pendrive application stop killing other processes? By restricting its permissions or something like that?

Comment: It sounds like the course has some terms of service that the software is designed to enforce.  You should address your options with the originator.  Advice on defeating your license restrictions isn't on topic.

Comment: There could be copyright issues if you try to copy these videos. Are you not able to take [handwritten notes](http://www2.open.ac.uk/students/skillsforstudy/how-to-take-notes.php)?

Comment: My purpose here is not to abuse the course material provided to me, nor to infringe any copyrights as I don't intend to distribute it to anyone else for my own gain. (In fact distributing to someone else is out of question as the course material is all encrypted and can only be accessed through the software interface of the pendrive.)
It's just that I need some more time to completely study and learn the course. And I can't afford to pay again for what I've already paid for. Some help in this regard would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit strange but have you checked where the video files are in the pendrive and copying it to your PC ?. 
Also try disconnecting the internet connection and pushing your date back.

Rgds,
Rtrj

Comment: No it's not that plain. Of course the files are encrypted and not in standard media file formats.

Answer (score 0):

one easy way to get around the limitation would be to run windows in a vm and record the video from the host operating system. this way the "service" won't be able to kill apps running on the host. the question is, does the app check if it's running in a virtualized environment?